# What would be a witty answer to ordinary sexism at work?

Tags: sexism

I work in a large famous web company, approximately 400 employees. Today one of the management recent recrutement gave a short speech in french whereas she is not, in front of the 400 employees. In between two speakers, out of nowhere, the big boss got really excited, so he took the mic, and said, "we are all glad that you speak french now, it's very sexy".

It was very awkward, it is no big deal, but even though I am a man, I felt really bad, somehow betrayed. People are posting anonymous comments on the wall of the cafeteria. There are loads of phrases like "inappropriate behaviour", "sexist remark"...

I am looking for a phrase, a mojo, something catchy, possibly famous, that would emphasis how I feel. Something I could write on a post-it and make everyone happy.

Comment: How would writing a catch phrase on a post it solve anything?

Comment: there are already dozens of catch phrases on the wall referring to the event (we are a "fun" company) I was hoping to find inspiration here

Comment: I would like to know why this question is being downvoted. While I don't think a witty answer is the most appropriate in this type of situation, plus I find it more appropriate to change a bit the focus of the question (example: "what is the best I can do in this situation"), just downvoating doesn't help much.

Comment: Re *I am looking for a phrase, a mojo, something catchy, possibly famous, that would emphasis how I feel.* The first (and second and third and ...) phrase that came to my mind: "Keep your thoughts to yourself".

Comment: @DarkPurpleShadow Because it's not a very useful question. Using catchphrases will not solve sexism. Taking action, like Tfish answered would do a lot more. If they are really stuck for such things, they could always google witty catch phrases. I feel, that this question is quite off topic, however that's my opinion, let the masses decide

Comment: @Draken: thanks, that is far more useful than just silently downvoting. I also don't find the catchphrasing approach very useful and would be glad if marmouset (btw, thanks for caring :) changed his approach.

Comment: Final CV cast, though this is not so much too broad, just blatantly off-topic. We don't do word requests. How are we supposed to know "how you feel" anyway?

Comment: At least he didn't tweet it.

Answer (score 5):

You should just report it to HR instead more so if it continues. A witty comment could make him think he was funny and could encourage that behavior further.

Comment: and the good thing is: enough witnesses!

Comment: well yes 400 is enough

Answer (score -3):

I think if the company culture is in right, then they guy already damaged himself by showing how unprofessional he is in front of the whole company, and the biggest damage to him is plainly saying nothing about it - he made himself look like an idiot not suited for the job - and everybody else look professional by going over the issue.

If the company culture is not right, there is no point to make in the company by any "witty responses". Witty responses are good to point thing to people who accidentally stumble and draw the wrong conclusions and they are best for things in small circles.

If you want to piss him off (**anonymously! I advise against it! - also make sure about the legal situation - I am not a lawyer!**): I am sure there is a presentation style in your company about values and mottos etc, and sometimes these things are put up as motivational wall decoration. Take this style and make an additional one (optically as close as possible to the original):
"We are all glad that you speak French now, it's very sexy (name of the guy, date)" Stick it over some of the motivational wall decoration close to his office and see how long it takes until it's removed.

Comment: Ahh yes, the old attributable quotes passive-aggressive approach. For added comedy, have several spares to put up as soon as it gets taken down

Comment: @JohnHC: It's not my style, but I know some people who would enjoy it....

Comment: that's the spirit. Everytime he talks on slack, girls are popping sexy emojis (swimsuits, lipsticks, kisses). I am having a nice day after all.

Comment: I wrote "women work matters" on the wall I am happy with it

Comment: Company culture seems to be right....